# Images are always served with name "unnamed.jpg" in Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am working on a PHP app on Google App Engine standard environment.

I upload an image to the app's associated bucket, then use this code to serve the image:

```
use \google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

// ...

$path = "gs://my-app.appspot.com/the_image_name.jpg"
$imageUrl = CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl($path, ['secure_url' => true, 'size' => 0]);
header("Location: $imageUrl");
```

There is of course a redirection to a page like this:

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/<some_hash>
```

The image displays correctly, but in the title of the browser it says "unnamed.jpg", and when I try to save the image to my computer the default name appears as "unnamed.jpg". This happens every time I upload an image, no matter its actual name, or if I do upload it through my app using the API or if I upload it directly to the bucket through the web cloud console.

Is there any way in which I can specify what name is used when serving the image?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the headers: 'Content-disposition', 'Content-Transfer-Encoding', & 'Content-Type'

Comment: Google creates a URL for serving the image and I must redirect my app's user to that Google serving URL. I can't directly set the headers for that response (because it's handled by Google).

Comment: in python i have access to `blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler` https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/webapp/blobstorehandlers#BlobstoreDownloadHandler where i can convert a GCS key into a blob key and App engine will serve that with without the redirect. If I browse the source of `BlobstoreDownloadHandler.send_blob` it is setting the special appengine header 'X-AppEngine-BlobKey' and then app engine must have some special code that detects this and then injects the GCS file into the response payload. perhaps you can emulate this in python

Answer (score 0):

`CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl` uses `googleusercontent.com` which is a "sandbox" and therefore you can't change the name of the file served.

I suggest you to take a look in [`CloudStorageTools::serve`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/refdocs/classes/google.appengine.api.cloud_storage.CloudStorageTools#serve) method where you will be able to set the name of the file with `save_as` parameter. Please note that the type is string and not boolean as it's mentioned in the documentation and `serve` will take some app engine compute time.

The code should look like this:

```
use \google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

// ...

$file_name = "gs://my-app.appspot.com/the_image_name.jpg"
$options = ['save_as' => 'the_image_name.jpg'];
CloudStorageTools::serve($file_name, $options);
```